# Django iterate all values from zip

Tags: python, django

first I zip all my lists just like

```
 books= zip(ID, bookName, *detail)
```

but as you see the detail has not only one element, I can not sure the number of list of detail. And the number is variable.

Than loop over it in templates like:

```
   {% for ID, bookName, detail, in books %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ID}}</td>
                <td>{{ bookName }}</td>
                <td>{{ detail }} </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

As I can not confirm the number of detail, I got the error message like "Need 3 values to unpack in for loop; got 5. "

Is there any method to get the right loop times when the list is variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enumerate over the tuples, and then iterate over the elements, so:

```
{% for record in books %}
  <tr>
    {% for item in record %}
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's cool! First time to know the record and item, very helpful!